# Dynamically insert values

Tags: php

I'd like to loop through form fields and dynamically take form field data and insert it into the database. I don't want to have to bind a value for each form field, but rather loop through the values in an array. It doesn't seem to be working the way I have it. Any suggestions?

Thanks

```
<?php
    $FormFields = array();
    $Values = array();
    global $i;
    $i = 0;

    $conn= new PDO(DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD);
    foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
        $FormFields[++$i] = $key;
        $Values[$i] = $value;

        echo $FormFields[$i] . "<br />";
        echo $Values[$i] . "<br />";

        //loop through all form fields and bind value
        $sql = "INSERT INTO sectiona ($FormFields[$i]) VALUES (:$i)";
        $st = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $st->bindValue(":$i", $Values[$i]);
        $st->execute();

    }
    echo "Total Fields: " . $i;
    $conn = null;

?>
```

EDIT:

Why does it create a new row for each data entry?
Shouldn't it just be one row?

[image: my image]

Answer (score 1):

You can't do `++$i` in the quotes. Move that part of the query out.

```
$field = $FormFields[++$i];
$sql = "INSERT INTO sectiona ($field) VALUES (:$i)";
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `$i` is being set properly.
I did a

```
 echo $i . " - " . $FormFields[$i] . " - " . $Values[$i] . "<br />";
```

line, it's giving proper output on URL `test.php?test=1&something=2&nothing=true` as

```
1 - test - 1 
2 - something - 2
3 - nothing - true
```

May be variable isn't exported in the query properly. Try:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO sectiona ('".$FormFields[$i]."') VALUES (:".$i.")";
$st = $conn->prepare($sql);
$st->bindValue(":".$i, $Values[$i]);
```

---

EDIT to answer your EDIT:
You are doing `$sql = "INSERT INTO sectiona ($FormFields[++$i]) VALUES (:$i)";`
You already incremented $i in first place `$FormFields[++$i] = $key;`. Don't do it again. That's why I had edited it to

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO sectiona ('".$FormFields[$i]."') VALUES (:".$i.")";
```

in first response.

Comment: Updated to answer your query.

Comment: I already changed that but it still creates a new row per iteration.